# Using XML data encoded to JSON on PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, laravel

I've just created a php file to query some data from an API. 
A normal returned data should be like :

```
{
@attributes: {
    Status: "OK"
},
Errors: { },
Warnings: { },
RequestedCommand: "checking",
CommandResponse: {
    @attributes: {
    Type: "check"
    },
    DomainCheckResult: [
        {
        @attributes: {
            Domain: "example1.com",
            Available: "true",
            ErrorNo: "0",
            Description: "",
            IsPremiumName: "false",
            PremiumRegistrationPrice: "0",
            PremiumRenewalPrice: "0",
            PremiumRestorePrice: "0",
            PremiumTransferPrice: "0",
            IcannFee: "0",
            EapFee: "0"
        }
        },
        {
        @attributes: {
            Domain: "example2.com",
            Available: "true",
            ErrorNo: "0",
            Description: "",
            IsPremiumName: "false",
            PremiumRegistrationPrice: "0",
            PremiumRenewalPrice: "0",
            PremiumRestorePrice: "0",
            PremiumTransferPrice: "0",
            IcannFee: "0",
            EapFee: "0"
        }
        },
    ]
},
Server: "asd",
GMTTimeDifference: "--5:00",
ExecutionTime: "2.622"
}
```

Now, When I try to get the attributes values such as "Domain" and "Available" and the other ones to put them in some variables, I do the following :

```
$client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request('POST', 'http://api.website.com/xml.response', [
        'form_params' => [
        'ApiUser' => 'myuser',
        'ApiKey' => 'apikey',
        'UserName' => 'myuser',
        'ClientIp' => 'myip',
        'Command' => 'check',
        'List' => $list
            ]
        ]);
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($res->getBody(),'SimpleXMLElement',LIBXML_NOCDATA);
        $json = json_encode($xml);
        $data = json_decode($json, true);
        echo $data->CommandResponse[0];
```

But it tells me :

> Trying to get property of non-object

What am I doing wrong? Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with the second parameter of the `json_decode` function. This tells the function if it should convert the json string into an array or an object (see the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)). In your case you create an array, but want to access it as an object. So either you change your `json_decode($json, true)` to `json_decode($json)` or you `echo $data->CommandResponse[0]` to `echo $data['CommandResponse'][0]`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: changing that will result in : `Undefined property: stdClass::$CommandResponse`

Comment: @M.Safari Can you please make `var_dump` of your `$data` variable? Is the first code you posted is the already transformed result (xml -> json) or is this the raw result that is returned?